# "Spider not found" error even though I have the name listed in the spider function?

Tags: python, scrapy

Here is my scrapy code thus far:

```
import scrapy
class Tripadvisor(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'Trip_advisor'
url = ['https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g188644-d604560-Reviews-Sofitel_Brussels_Europe-Brussels.html']

def parse(self,response):
    SET_SELECTOR = '.ratings_chart'
    for data in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):

        Excellent_Selector = '//*[@id="taplc_location_detail_overview_hotel_map_pins_default_0"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/span[3]'
        VeryGood_Selector = '//*[@id="taplc_location_detail_overview_hotel_map_pins_default_0"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/span[3]'
        Average_Selector = '//*[@id="taplc_location_detail_overview_hotel_map_pins_default_0"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/span[3]'
        Poor_Selector = '//*[@id="taplc_location_detail_overview_hotel_map_pins_default_0"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[4]/span[3]'
        Terrible_Selector = '//*[@id="taplc_location_detail_overview_hotel_map_pins_default_0"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[5]/span[3]'
        yield {
            'Excellent': data.xpath(Excellent_Selector).extract_first(),
            'Very Good': data.xpath(VeryGood_Selector).extract_first(),
            "Average": data.xpath(Average_Selector).extract_first(),
            "Poor":data.xpath(Poor_Selector).extract_first(),
            "Terrible":data.xpath(Terrible_Selector).extract_first()
        }
```

Whenever I run `scrapy crawl Trip_advisor` in the project directory, I keep getting `KeyError: Spider not found: Trip_advisor`, how do I fix this error?

I am confused since I clearly have the name `Trip_advisor` defined within the `Tripadvisor` class.

Edit: Traceback error in command line, thanks to @furas

```
C:\Users\dh228\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\tutorial>scrapy crawl Trip_advisor                                                                    
2017-12-26 01:41:30 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.2.0 started (bot: tutorial)                                                                                        
2017-12-26 01:41:30 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': ` 'tutorial', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders']}                                                                                                                                      
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                               
File "c:\users\dh228\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 41, in load                                       
return self._spiders[spider_name]                                                                                                                          
KeyError: 'Trip_advisor'  

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                               
File "c:\users\dh228\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", 
line 193, in _run_module_as_main                                                   
"__main__", mod_spec)                                                                                                                                        
File "c:\users\dh228\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py", 
line 85, in _run_code                                                              
exec(code, run_globals)                                                                                                                                      
File "C:\Users\dh228\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-
32\Scripts\scrapy.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>                                            
File "c:\users\dh228\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 142, in execute                                        
_run_print_help(parser, _run_command, cmd, args, opts)                                                                                                       
File "c:\users\dh228\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 88, in _run_print_help                                 
func(*a, **kw)                                                                                                                                               
File "c:\users\dh228\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\scrapy\cmdline.py", line 149, in _run_command                                   
cmd.run(args, opts)                                                                                                                                          
File "c:\users\dh228\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\scrapy\commands\crawl.py", line 57, in run                                      
self.crawler_process.crawl(spname, **opts.spargs)                                                                                                            
File "c:\users\dh228\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 162, in crawl                                          
crawler = self.create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)                                                                                                          
File "c:\users\dh228\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 190, in create_crawler                                 
return self._create_crawler(crawler_or_spidercls)                                                                                                            
File "c:\users\dh228\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 194, in _create_crawler                                
spidercls = self.spider_loader.load(spidercls)                                                                                                               
File "c:\users\dh228\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\scrapy\spiderloader.py", line 43, in load                                       
raise KeyError("Spider not found: {}".format(spider_name))                                                                                                 
KeyError: 'Spider not found: Trip_advisor'`
```

Comment: Make sure your project is not called scrapy.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) - there are other useful informations.

Comment: Your code seems to have indentation errors

Comment: @kessi The project is named "Accor"

Comment: @TarunLalwani Ah yes I shouldve indented it properly when I entered it into stackoverflow. In actuality, it is indented correctly

Comment: BTW: and put Traceback in question as text,

Comment: @furas I just input the Traceback in the question. Thank you so much

Comment: I don't see problem in Traceback so maybe you have wrong indentions and `name = 'Trip_advisor'` is not inside `class Tripadvisor(scrapy.Spider)`, or file with `class Tripadvisor` is in wrong place - it has to be in subfolder `spiders`

Comment: Try `scrapy list` to see all available spiders. Try creating a new spider with no content other than the basic structure. Do you have any other active spiders running? If so, make sure this new spider is located in the same folder. If not: double check whether you're using the correct folder.

Comment: What is the filename of your file? Can you try using `scrapy runspider <filename>` and see if that helps?

Comment: Have you called in the Items.py file?  I.e. `from Trip_advisor.items import Trip_advisorItem` Though obviously I don’t know your file naming system but it should be in the folder above your spider, the same one as the pipelines.py file